Not able to set memlock value to unlimited for DSE Cassandra
We are installing DSE Cassandra as a tarball install by creating our own Docker Image. As per their recommended best practices we have to set few values like "memlock" to unlimited for better performance.  Refer: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.9/managing/configure/recommended-settings.html#set-user-resource-limits
We have tried the same by adding the following lines into "/etc/security/limits.conf" file.
<non-root-dbuser> - memlock unlimited
<non-root-dbuser> - nofile 1048576
<non-root-dbuser> - nproc 32768
<non-root-dbuser> - as unlimited

The non-root-dbuser is our user with which we start our Cassadra Docker container
#Docker file reference
ADD limits.conf /etc/security/limits.conf
ADD dse-version-bin.tar.gz /opt    
USER <non-root-dbuser>
ENTRYPOINT <start-cassandra>

But when we start the DSE container, as a POD in Kubernetes. We are not able to see the memlock value being persisted.
$ ulimit -l
64

Also getting the following WARN in logs.

WARN  [DSE main thread] 2024-11-18 09:08:04,077
NativeLibrary.java:195 - Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM). This can
result in part of the JVM being swapped out, especially with mmapped
I/O enabled. Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK or run Cassandra as root.

Please let us know if anyone has already faced this issue, and how did you overcome. Also does anybody know the impact if the user-limits (memlock unlimited) is not set for cassandra.

Without memlock unlimited, you couild get the error describe here: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/faq/#oom-map-failed

Can you run cat /etc/security/limits.conf with Docker exec and verify that the file is set properly?

Yes the file "/etc/security/limits.conf" contains the contents set in Docker Image
 - memlock unlimited
 - nofile 1048576
 - nproc 32768
 - as unlimited
